# Outlook web ignores the styling

Tags: html, css, outlook, office365, html-email

The code works in Gmail and in Outlook, but when I'm checking that button with the Outlook Web version (Outlook.com Edge, Windows 10) there is not styling at all and [if mso] conditional statement doesn't work - it just not recognizing the Outlook. The whole button itself looks like a plain text.

```html
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
 <!-- Set align to "left" -->
  <tr>
   <td>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:100px;" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#6BBB5E" fillcolor="#6BBB5E">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;">
          Button Text
        </center>
      </v:roundrect>
      <![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!-- --><span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><a alias="" class="button" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;background-color:#6BBB5E;width:100px;display:inline-block;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 20px;/* bigger padding */
    text-align:center;/* color */
    color:#FFFFFF;/* Black text */
    border-radius:20px;/* Rounded corners */
    border:none;cursor:pointer;line-height:100%;" title="">Button text</a> </span></span><!--<![endif]--></td></tr></table>
```

So is it there anything that I can change in my conditional statements?

I tried to adopt the code, but it didn't work. I also tried to change the conditional [if mso] but it didn't help.

Comment: If conditions or scripts in general are not supported well by email clients.

Comment: Have you tried testing it with a url in the href?

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, VML and email client compatibility is always great fun.

I believe the issue is that VML is not supported in ***all*** outlook versions anymore. It's only supported in some. VML is deprecated since IE9 and I believe they've been working on phasing it out. The web outlook you were using probably was one of the clients in which it was phased out in. Unfortunately, it's very hard to target the web client you mentioned specifically. I believe it falls under MSO 16 (Outlook 2016) which also includes web outlook, windows 10 and 11 mail, as well as Microsoft 365 and a few other things that still use VML.

This is the code I got working:

```html
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
        <!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" stroked="f" arcsize="50%" fillcolor="#6BBB5E" style="width:100px; height:40px; v-text-anchor:middle;">
                <w:anchorlock/>
            <![endif]-->
                <center style="background-color:#6BBB5E; border-radius:20px; color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height:100%; padding:10px 20px; width:100px;">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
                        <span class="txt" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Button text</span>
                    </a>
                </center>
            <!--[if mso]>
            </v:roundrect>
        <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I've done is that I put the opening and closing VML in `mso` conditionals while keeping HTML code outside of comments in between the the VML-rendered code. This way if the client is outlook, it attempts to render the VML. If it isn't or cannot render VML, it will still have the non-mso content to fall back on.